# A Way to kill an activity in Android

Tags: android

In my android application, I start another activity using 'startActivity'.
Is there anyway for me to kill that activity I started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stop the other activity by calling [`Activity.finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()).  Alternatively, you can use [`Activity.finishActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity(int)) to finish an activity started by `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried you suggestion. 
I did  startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")), 1111);

And then I did 
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 1111:
                finishActivity(1111);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
I see my debug statement, but the WebView Activity does not get killed.

Any other idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the new activity, the old activity goes onPause(). you could try calling finish() in the onPause() of the old activity.